# Data fetched form database is another than stored

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

So, i use sequelize.j and mysql.
Config.json:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "******",
    "password": "******",
    "database": "******",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "timezone": "Europe/Warsaw"
  },
  "production": {
  }
}
```

And i save Date to database.
Data in database is stored rigth - valid time.

But if i select from database, time is in wrong timezone.

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you NODE_ENV mode and never console time in node js because it automatically converted into iso format, you can try in console

```
new Date();
```

or

```
new Date().toISOString();
```

Comment: `> new Date();
Fri Jun 03 2016 10:53:31 GMT+0200 (CEST)` On console is all fine.

Comment: are you using node js REPL for  console

Comment: For app with problem time works good to if i use ``console.log(new Date);`` before fetch